# Retrofit 2 API Can I use local file path or json string instead of url?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

Hello I am working on an `Android` App which uses `retrofit` API getting response from server. Retrofit Automatically parse the json response and creates objects of `POJO` class. I am storing that json into sqlite and if internet is not connected call the json from sqllite, facing difficulty have to parse json manually.

Is there any way I use retrofit library to parse json and make pojo from json string or file path?My code is here to fetch from url:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("getResponse")
Observable<UserResponse> getResponse(@Field("token") String token);
```

I want something like this if internet is not connected.

```
@FromStringEncoded
Observable<UserResponse> getResponseOffline(@Field("token") String token);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use `Google's GSON` Library that allows you to convert `json` to `POJO` and vice versa. Fetch `json` from `sqlite` and parse it using `gson`.

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
UserResponse userResponse= gson.fromJson(jsonInStringFromDb,UserResponse.class);
```

You can also parse `JSON` from file using `Gson`.

JSON to Java object, read it from a file.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), Staff.class);
```

Comment: I am using **gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(0),List.class);**
need to make object of list like this:
**List<List<UserResponse.class>>**
how can I make it?

Comment: Gson gson=new Gson();
List<List<UserResponse>> listResponse=gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(0),new TypeToken<List<List<UserResponse>>>(){}.getType());

Comment: I don't like this answer. When using plain Gson, you need to add some converters to in(that you've already installed into your project's gson.) The proper way is to intercept the request and put new json into the response

Answer (score 13):

You don't mentioned proposes. I use below solution for mocking server in app on very early stage of development when real server doesn't work yet.

So you can use interceptors in OkHttp. Like this:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();       
builder.addInterceptor(new MockClient(context));
```

and MockClient looks like this:

```
public class MockClient implements Interceptor {

    Context context;

    public MockClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        HttpUrl url = chain.request().url();
        Log.d("TAG","url="+url);
        //here determine what to do base on url.
        //e.g.:
        switch(url.encodedPath()) {
           case "some/path" :
            String response = readJsonFieleFromAssestOrAnyOtherStorage();
            return new Response.Builder()
                        .code(200)
                        .message(response)
                        .request(chain.request())
                        .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                                    .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), response.getBytes()))
                        .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                        .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I add logging to your custom MockClient? The mock client is working for me but I don't see any logs. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What exactly want you to log?

Comment: I wanted to add something to what HttpLoggingInterceptor() offers to your MockCleint and change the level at which the interceptor logs. For example, I would like to log the request and responses line and I can achieve it by this code in HttpLoggingInterceptor.

           ***val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor() 
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY***

Comment: In this solution you have to implement it by you own. I added one place where you can put log.

Answer (score 0):

THere's no point in using it from the local `filesystem`-  `retrofit` is for `http requests`.  If you need to just `parse JSON`, use `GSON` or `Jackson`-  those are the two `libraries` that `RetroFit` uses to `parse json`.  Both `libraries` are fairly easy to use.